# Wiremock trigger a rest post call

Tags: functional-testing, wiremock

I understand that wiremock is used to simulate a service's response, given a request. However, I am wondering if we could use wiremock to mock a service and then use this mocked service to send out a post call to trigger a process.

The reason I want to do this is because I need to mock a service A and it will call a api on service B, where B will call A back. So I am thinking if I could use A to trigger B's procedure and then verify A got a request from B (a wiremock record?).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the webhooks extension:
https://wiremock.org/docs/webhooks-and-callbacks/

The webhook extension uses WireMock's `PostServeAction` hook to make an HTTP request out to another service.

You can use templating to dynamically set the URL, method, headers and body content.